# java.lang.NullPointerException: InputStream.read

Tags: android

How can I identify what is causing me this Null Pointer Exception? It's a device related issue, I don't get it in my device.

This is the stack trace I got from Google Developer:

```
Samsung Galaxy J2 (j2lte), 1024MB RAM, Android 5.1
Report 1 of 5

java.lang.NullPointerException: 
at com.android.okio.OkBuffer.write (OkBuffer.java:574)
at com.android.okio.OkBuffer.read (OkBuffer.java:610)
at com.android.okio.RealBufferedSource.read (RealBufferedSource.java:56)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection$UnknownLengthSource.read 
(HttpConnection.java:584)
at com.android.okio.RealBufferedSource$1.read (RealBufferedSource.java:174)
at java.io.InputStream.read (InputStream.java:162)
at com.OnlineRecorder.home.MyService$11.run (Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)
```

Here is my code how I record and write data, this happens in a service in my app:

Then I start Recording:

```
        private void startRecording() {
        isRecording = true;
        recordingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                filename = getFilename();
                //int bytesRead = 0;
                try {
                    url = new URL(selectedRadio);
                    inputStream = url.openStream();
                    fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(filename, true);
                    int c;
                    //isRecording=true;
                    final byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];
                    while ((c = inputStream.read(tmp))!= -1) {
                        //c = inputStream.read();
                        fileOutputStream.write(tmp,0,c);
                        fileOutputStream.getFD().sync();
                        //bytesRead++;
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, "AudioRecorder Thread");
        recordingThread.start();
    }
```

then I stop recording like this:

```
       public void stopRecording(){
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    if(inputStream != null && fileOutputStream != null) {
                        inputStream.close();
                        fileOutputStream.getFD().sync();
                        fileOutputStream.close();
                        File savedFile = new File(filename);
                        sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(savedFile)));
                        isRecording = false;
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

The problem is not as easy as it seems, it's tricky, the null pointer exception shouldn't even be reproduced to begin with, because I already have in code an if else statement in which i make sure there is an open connection and data being streamed before i even start recording (I check if radio is being played or not) so logically null shouldn't be thrown in any case.

After some research the problem is common and it may have to do with this as stated in this reply in another website:

> it's likely this NPE is caused by a concurrency problem in your code. For example, using or closing an InputStream from multiple threads.

Comment: Do you have a class called `RealBufferedSource ` that you have created??

Comment: no i only have those code, and these codes i call them from a background thread even though they run in a service..like this     public void startRecordThread()
    {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                AppLog.logString("Start Recording");
                startRecording();
            }
        }).start();
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just want to confirm that I solved my problem, the Null pointer exception is caused by a concurrency problem in my code caused by opening and closing an InputStream from multiple threads.

I fixed it by interrupting the thread that opens an inputStream before I start the thread that close the input stream.

in code I added "recordingThread.interrupt();" and I add an if else statement to double check that the thread was interrupted successfully before I close the inputStream: "if(recordingThread.isInterrupted()) then..etc"

Answer (score 1):

for now you can do this

```
 private void startRecording() {
            isRecording = true;
            recordingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    filename = getFilename();
                    //int bytesRead = 0;
                    try {
                        url = new URL(selectedRadio);
                        inputStream = url.openStream();
//do null check for input stream
                        if (inputStream != null) {
                            fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(filename, true);
                            int c;
                            //isRecording=true;
                            final byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];
                            while ((c = inputStream.read(tmp)) != -1) {
                                //c = inputStream.read();
                                fileOutputStream.write(tmp, 0, c);
                                fileOutputStream.getFD().sync();
                                //bytesRead++;
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, "AudioRecorder Thread");
            recordingThread.start();
        }
```

Comment: Hello, that didn't solve the problem, I was lucky to catch the problem after many testing and it happened when I close the connection at "stopRecording()" 

after some research i found out it may has to do with multithreading as i am using two different threads to open and close the connection..as it stated in this comment in another website:

"it's likely this NPE is caused by a concurrency problem in your code. For example, using or closing an InputStream from multiple threads."